How to generate agora token in spring boot application?
I am generating an agora rtc token, but getting invalid token error when token pass to join a meeting.
This is my token generation method.....
public String generateTokenWithUid(int uid, String channelName, Date meetingStartTime, Date meetingEndTime) {
        logger.info("Generating token");
        RtcTokenBuilder2 tokenBuilder = new RtcTokenBuilder2();

        // Calculate token validity
        long validFrom = meetingStartTime.getTime() - (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 2 hours before
        long validUntil = meetingEndTime.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 5 hours after

        // Set expiration based on the validity range
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime < validFrom) {
            tokenExpirationInSeconds = (int) ((validUntil - validFrom) / 1000);
        } else {
            tokenExpirationInSeconds = (int) ((validUntil - currentTime) / 1000);
        }

        return tokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appId, appCertificate, channelName, uid, Role.ROLE_SUBSCRIBER, tokenExpirationInSeconds, privilegeExpirationInSeconds);
    } 


Hi there please add the full error message and/or the full stacktrace of the error to your question (please not as a comment)
